# Command-line public-key-encryption utility

Tags: linux, command-line, embedded-linux, public-key-encryption

I'm looking for a "simple" linux command-line encryption mechanism to log my SDTOUT/STDERR prints to a file.

Currently I just append the output of my program to a file - but I'm looking for something like this:

```
./myProgram | encryptionProgram publicKey >> logFile
```

that I can then decrypt with a privateKey

Note: I'm *not* looking for an encrypted filesystem solution, I want to pipe it straight to an open VFAT filesystem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an interesting thread on [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12260/how-to-encrypt-messages-text-with-rsa-using-openssl).

That should do what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks Otto - that is the answer to my question, but not a solution I was looking for. Do you know of any solution that does _not_ use OpenSSL? I'm running BusyBox for MIPS32

Comment: I think in any case you'll need to use a cryptographic library. Why don't you just compile openssl for mips32?